# Download manager not callback when the URL is HTTPS

Tags: android, networking, ssl, android-networking, android-download-manager

Here is how I download the file, it works on http but when I use https, it does not callback, thanks for helping.

```
  DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(Constant.request_imageFolder + item.user_id + "/" + item.record_url));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    //request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
    }
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(tmp_record));
    enqueue = mgr.enqueue(request);
```

The oncomplete code, which is not call when I use https

```
onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
String action = intent.getAction();
if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
Query query = new Query();
query.setFilterById(enqueue);
if (query != null) {
Cursor c = mgr.query(query);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
String mediaType = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE));
                if (mediaType.equals("image/jpeg")) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    share.performClick();
                                } else if (mediaType.equals("video/mp4")) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    play();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

I tried to debug but the error detection message is at the callback so there is no hints about the root of problem , only knowing that it is caused by https. How can I fix it? thanks for helping?

Comment: for https connection u need to create httpsConnection using truststore or simliar apis

Comment: Thanks for reply, is that mean Download Manager does not support https connection?

Comment: no i didnt mean that , i simply mean is for https connection need certificate that can be trusted in android, may be ur url cert is not present in default android cert